# Postifx - temporary lookup failure

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I have problem with my mail server. I have postfix and dovecot with current configuration:
/etc/postfix/main.cf

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = learn-linux.eu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = learn-linux.eu
mydestination =  localhost, mail.learn-linux.eu, learn-linux.eu
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp


virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-domains-maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailbox-maps.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-alias-maps.cf,
        mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf
```

master.cf

```
#
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master" or
# on-line: http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html).
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       y       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     unix  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}
```

When i connect from telnet to port 25  i write mail from all it's ok, but when i write rcpt to, then receive temporary lookup failure. For mail server configuration i used this tutorial https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mysql/

I can connect to pop3 without any problem, all works fine, but smtp i have problem and sending  e-mail.

I don't know what is wrong with my configuration.
Log from /var/log/mail.log

```
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 2EEC43EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.2EEC43EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 2EEC43EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 2F3743EAA9: uid=0 from=<pawel@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 2F3743EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.2F3743EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "pawel.cyrklaf@gmail.com"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 2F3743EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for pawel.cyrklaf@gmail.com -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 2F5D93EAA9: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 2F5D93EAA9: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 2F5D93EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.2F5D93EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 2F5D93EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 2F9843EAA9: message has been queued for 6 days
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 2F9843EAA9: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 2F9843EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.2F9843EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 2F9843EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 306D23EAA9: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 306D23EAA9: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 306D23EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.306D23EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 306D23EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 30B583EAA9: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 30B583EAA9: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 30B583EAA9: message-id=<20190915130805.30B583EAA9@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:08:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 30B583EAA9: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:08:11 learn-linux dovecot: master: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=10111 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 15 15:08:12 learn-linux dovecot: log: Warning: Killed with signal 15 (by pid=1 uid=0 code=kill)
Sep 15 15:08:12 learn-linux dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.27 (c0f36b0) starting up for imap, pop3, lmtp (core dumps disabled)
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 3F96D3EA21: message has been queued for 2 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 3F96D3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 3F96D3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.3F96D3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 3F96D3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 3FFD23EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 3FFD23EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: 3FFD23EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.3FFD23EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: connect to mysql server 127.0.0.1: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: 3FFD23EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 413CA3EA21: message has been queued for 6 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 413CA3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 413CA3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.413CA3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 413CA3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 4165F3EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 4165F3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 4165F3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.4165F3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 4165F3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 41A5E3EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 41A5E3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 41A5E3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.41A5E3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 41A5E3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 41D153EA21: message has been queued for 2 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 41D153EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: 41D153EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.41D153EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: 41D153EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 41F863EA21: uid=0 from=<pawel@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 41F863EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.41F863EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "pawel.cyrklaf@gmail.com"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 41F863EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for pawel.cyrklaf@gmail.com -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 422C63EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 422C63EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: 422C63EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.422C63EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: 422C63EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 4253D3EA21: message has been queued for 6 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 4253D3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 4253D3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.4253D3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 4253D3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 42A4E3EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 42A4E3EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: 42A4E3EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.42A4E3EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10105]: warning: 42A4E3EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: warning: 42C713EA21: message has been queued for 1 days
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/pickup[10100]: 42C713EA21: uid=0 from=<root>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: 42C713EA21: message-id=<20190915130905.42C713EA21@learn-linux.eu>
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-email2email.cf lookup error for "root@learn-linux.eu"
Sep 15 15:09:05 learn-linux postfix/cleanup[10103]: warning: 42C713EA21: virtual_alias_maps map lookup problem for root@learn-linux.eu -- message not accepted, try again later
```

Comment: I'd need the specific log to have a chance at knowing what was wrong.

Comment: @DanielFarrell hi :) I added to my post logs from mail.log

Answer (score 0):

I finded solution. When i added my server IP to mynetworks i can send email with any problem :)

Comment: it makes sense with your logs.  `mynetworks` is allowed in `smtpd_relay_restrictions`.  Sine `defer_unauth_destination` is also there, mail is deferred instead of being rejected outright when it's not a valid local destination and relaying is unauthorized.  Note that you also have it set up to allow sasl authenticated smtp, but don't have that configured.  http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#server_dovecot_comm

Comment: If you added an explanation I'd upvote that answer.  Maybe it can help somebody else.

Comment: @DanielFarrell Hey, I can send messages outside of what I see, but they don't reach me. Another problem is that I can not connect to the mail server from the outside, i.e. I can from the VPS level, but not with Thunderbird. What should I change to make it work?

Comment: If you're saying that eg the gmail address is being sent by postfix but not showing up in your inbox, you're probably triggering gmail's spam recognition because your mailserver's IP isn't in the domain's SPF records, has not DKIM set up, doesn't have PTR records set up or other reason.  Check your spam folder too.  For remote thunderbird, you'll need to ensure either pop or imap is listening on your public IP or 0.0.0.0 (all ips), and also allowed through any firewall(s).  Each of these topics should be a separate question.

Comment: @DanielFarrell ok, so i'll add new post with my problem